# VS Code : Python 3 : How do you change a variable whilst debugging?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, python-3.6, windows-server-2012

I've read you are supposed to be able to hover over a variable and a tool tip comes up that you can modify.
Yet. I can't seem to do that.
I wondered if someone can enlighten me what I need to do?

**VS Code : 1.23.1 on Windows Server 2012 RC2 via VMWare Fusion on a Mac**
[image: VS Code : 1.23.1]

**Marketplace IDE Python Plugin**
[image: Extensions]

**Showing Python version registered in IDE status bar**

[image: Python 3.6]

**OS on which the IDE runs**
[image: Windows Server 2012 RC2]

**How OS is hosted**

[image: VM Ware Fusion]
[image: Hign Sierra]

**Tooltip**

[image: Debug Tooltip. Can't edit!]

**Debug Menu**

[image: Debug Menu]

**Debug Sidebar**

[image: Debug Sidebar]

Heres' a [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) to the appropriate docs AFAIK.

Here's my [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1757) to Extension developers on Github

1. **Is this even feasible with the Python Plugin?**
2. **Are there other Python 3 debugger plugins that have that feature?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

vscode v1.60 is adding the ability to set values in the "Watch" view.  From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#watch-view-set-value-of-expressions:

#### WATCH view: set value of expressions

Now it is possible to set the value of an watched expression in the WATCH view using the Set Value action in the context menu.

Shows WATCH view with the Set Value action selected in the context menu

[image: release notes "Set Value" of watch expressions]

Note that debug extensions have to opt into this feature in order for Set Value to be available. For now, the JS-debug, C#, and C++ extensions support this, but we expect other debug extensions to follow soon.

---

Previous answer:

Find the variable you want to change in the "Variables" subpanel, not in the "Watch" subpanel unfortunately.  And <kbd>Right CLick</kbd> it there.  "Set Value" is an option in its context menu.

See  [data inspection in vscode debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_data-inspection).