# Watch window: is it read only by design?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've noticed the Watch window doesn't give me the "Add to Watch" or "Set Value" options the Variables window gives when debugging C++. This distinction seems odd, at least when coming from Visual Studio. Is there any way to add this functionality?

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not Visual Studio - they're not even related. Microsoft loves naming things for maximum confusion.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Absolutely. "Managed Pointer" is one of my favourites.

Comment: Well, it's not that I'm looking for a clone, but a smooth debugging experience would be nice. :-) Not being able to watch members of another watch seems an unnecessary restriction.

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50543550/836330 `Set Value` is being added to the `Warch` view.